# Get a value from xml reponse

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
    <response>
    <result code="1000">
      <msg lang="nl">De transactie is succesvol afgerond.</msg>
    </result>
    <trID>
      <clTRID>300100</clTRID>
      <svTRID>602C9E44-3F79-564D-5A53-C9689F088A1C</svTRID>
    </trID>
  </response>
</epp>
```

I need the result code from the xml in a string.
I already tried it with *simpleXml* :

```
$resCode = new \SimpleXMLElement($info);
$text = (string)$resCode->result;`
```

my xml is stored in `$info`

But this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML path is completely off. Try this according to the xml you posted:

```
$text = (string)$resCode->response->result["code"];
```

(Hint: the first node "epp" is not needed as it is the root node. So your path starts from inside this root node.)

Some samples:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Sometimes, reading the documentation helps.